# New Apex Code from WSDL

Tags: salesforce

I've generated an Apex class from a WSDL using the online tool but the generated code has the service url hard coded in multiple places. I want the code to look up the service url in a config object so that I can point it at a staging server and then switch it to live without having to re-generate code.

Shall I just look up which generated class to use or should I edit the generated code so that it looks up the service URL or is there a way of parameterising the service URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would update the generated code. I've done that before with no impact on the web service call.

You may want to look into using [**Custom Settings**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) (list settings would probably be best in this case) to store your service URL.

Using custom settings, it would look something like this:

```
List<WebServiceSettings__c> wss = WebServiceSettings__c.getall().values();
//... other code ...
public String endpoint_x = wss[0].URL__c;
```

You would need to change all references to the web service URL in the generated code to `wss[0].URL__c`.

Comment: How can you reference URL__c on a List? Shouldn't it be wss[0].URL__c? Also, when you do a regeneration from a WSDL, are you able to do a string replace to update all the hard coded URL references with a code look up?

Comment: Thanks for catching that (about the List reference); I updated the answer. You should be able to do a search and replace to change the references on the generated code, but I haven't tested that. I have only changed the references manually.

Comment: I've got it working Matthew. I just manually changed all the hard coded URLs with a call to a static method on a class which looks up a custom settings object. I even added in a 'Path' variable which goes in between the URL and the service file in one place. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Matthew, do you know if its possible to make an external web link that a tab points to be dynamic based on the same custom setting values?

Comment: Maybe if it's a Visualforce page w/an iframe instead of a plain Web Tab; that way you can bind a custom setting to the iframe src. You may need to have a very basic controller to return the Custom Setting variable, though. I don't think it would be possible with a Web Tab. 

Also, you should create a new question, instead of adding comments on this one, for something like this.

Comment: Yes... I got a bit anxious about starting another Saleforce question after this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930501/package-not-found-the-requested-package-does-not-exist-or-has-been-deleted#comment12685129_9930501.